# Cannot add controls outside wrapper class

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, owl-carousel

I'm using `owl-carousel` in wordpress and I'm trying to get the same html result displayed on the [site](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-classes.html):

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded">
    <div class="owl-stage-outer">
        <div class="owl-stage">
            <div class="owl-item">...</div>
            <div class="owl-item">...</div>
            <div class="owl-item">...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="owl-controls">
        <div class="owl-nav">
            <div class="owl-prev">prev</div>
            <div class="owl-next">next</div>
        </div>
        <div class="owl-dots">
            <div class="owl-dot active"><span></span></div>
            <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
            <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

as you can see there is the `owl-stage-outer` that contains the items of the slider, and at the bottom we can find the `owl-controls` class that contains the buttons to navigate to right or left.

Now in wordpress I've this template structure:

```
<div id="owl-featured" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">

    <?php //Check if only one post is featured ?>

    <?php if ( is_home() && !is_paged() && ( ot_get_option('featured-posts-count') == '1') && $featured->have_posts() ): // No slider if 1 post is featured ?>

        <?php while ($featured->have_posts() ): $featured->the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part('content-featured'); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php elseif ( is_home() && !is_paged() && ( ot_get_option('featured-posts-count') !='0') && $featured->have_posts() ): // Show slider if posts are not 1 or 0 ?>

        <?php while ( $featured->have_posts() ): $featured->the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part('content-featured'); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="owl-controls">
        <div class="owl-pagination"></div>
        <div class="owl-buttons"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've created a div that is the carousel container, and inside of it I've inserted the wordpress query to get the content, now as you can see at the end of the condition I've the `owl-controls`, infact I need to get the control outside of the `owl-wrapper`, as the first example provided, but the result that I get is the following:

```
<div id="owl-featured" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="owl-wrapper-outer">
        <div class="owl-wrapper">
            <div class="owl-item">
            <div class="owl-item">
            ... 
            ...
            <div class="owl-item"> 
               <div class="owl-controls">
                   <div class="owl-pagination"></div>
                   <div class="owl-buttons"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

as you can see the `owl-controls` is inside the `owl-item` and I don't understand why happen this, I'm stuck on this from three hours and I can't manage to found a solution.

PS: This is my js initialization of the slider:

```
$("#owl-featured").owlCarousel({
    nav: true,
    navContainer: '.owl-buttons',
    dotData: true,
    dotsContainer: '.owl-pagination',
    dotClass: 'owl-page',
    stageOuterClass: 'owl-wrapper-outer',
    stageClass: 'owl-wrapper',
    navContainerClass: 'owl-controls',
    navText : ['prev','next'],
    items : 3,
    itemsDesktop : [1440,3],
    itemsDesktopSmall : [1024,3],
    itemsTablet: [768,2],
    itemsTabletSmall: [719,1],
    itemsMobile : [479,1]
});
```

someone know where is the bug?

Comment: Is the result html you showed from page page source code or from browser inspector? If the second - take look at source code to find out where you lost some closing divs

Comment: @Anarion yep, there is no div unclosed, just a bad inner of the pagination

Answer (score 0):

@Aalok, you may first need see the basic demo:
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/basic.html

1. Before init Owl carousel, keep your items clean as basic demo;
2. You can only custom item content "`<h4>number</h4>`";(It's enought for most case);
3. About your custom control, you need add out of "owl-carousel" and add custom click event.
4. When you init the Owl carousel, the owl help wrap your item with "owl-item", and then wrap all you items with "owl-stage", then add owl's control dom "owl-controls", and wrap "owl-stage" "owl-controls" with "owl-stage-outer";